# How do I reset my admin password

Tags: password

When I login, system accepts my password to use system.  But, when I try to update software programs, system says "manipulation error" or something like that.

Went to login screen with Ubuntu recovery mode and tried to reset password using `mount -re`, etc but says password unchanged.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you tried `sudo apt-get update` on the command line? Exactly how and where you get the "manipulation error".

Comment: "or something like that" — if you expect people to help you, a more detailed description of your actual problem and what led up to it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found this and it worked for me:

How to reset your root / admin password in Ubuntu:

(It may not work in 12.10 if you have used full disk encryption)

Instructions:

> Reboot to the Grub Menu. (Hold down Left-Shift Key if you have a
>   single boot system)
>
> Choose Recovery Mode
>
> Select Root -- Drop to root shell prompt
>
> mount -o rw,remount /
>
> ls /home
>
> passwd username
>
> reboot

To test out new password:

> su username
>
> sudo su
>
> reboot